# Camel Routes (tab) not displayed in Hawtio

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

Our application is spring boot application with Apache camel routes.

Application's information like JMX, Runtime, Spring boot are exposed through hawtio.

But we are not able to see apache camel routes in hawtio.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding following dependency, we able to see camel (tab / plugins) in hawtio GUI.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
  <version>${version.camel}</version>
</dependency>
```

http://localhost:8080/actuator/hawtio

[image]

And also make sure jolokia and actuator end points are also exposed.